# How to prevent Qt 6.0 Installer from crashing?

Tags: qt, installation, qt-installer, qt6

## Here’s what happens

I open the installer, choose the packages I want(I choose to install some 1.7 GB of components), everything goes well.

But then when I click on the `Install` button, and Qt installer crashes! And by crashes I mean it crashes, Windows DOES NOT tell me it is not responding. The window just gets invisible from the taskbar.

There also is no possibility that it is installing in the background, as I waited for approx. 5 mins, and when I checked in the folder where I was going to install it, I didn’t find a SINGLE component installed!

How to solve that?

Comment: Are you installing from a Qt.io account login or did you download some off-line pre-built installation package? Which version of Windows? Are you trying to install multiple versions of Qt at the same time? There is a known issue with that. https://forum.qt.io/topic/93175/qt-unified-windows-x86-3-0-5-online-crashes-when-installing-qt-5-9-6-5-11-1

Answer (score 0):

I asked some questions earlier because a person needs more information. It also depends on what compiler you have. There are many many known issues with Qt 6.x.
The default kit doesn't work with MSVC2019
https://forum.qt.io/topic/120357/wrong-kit-for-qt-6-0-0-msvc2019-64bit/5
Qt 6.0 has install issues with GLib 6
https://youtu.be/IZy6FMQlaNg
There also appears to be significant problems with OpenGL.
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/20499

People seem to still be able to get off-line installers, and, as this French typing person found out, you have to be careful because it appears there are some 32-bit Windows kits.

https://forum.qt.io/topic/123027/installation-qt6-on-windows/7

If you try running them on a 64-bit Windows 10, they crash.

If this doesn't answer your question, you need to supply

1. Which Windows Version
2. 32 or 64-bit
3. off-line or on-line installer?

Comment: Please put more effort in ansering the question. Supplying a bunch of links is considered a bad practice. You have to provide the essence of the solution in your post. Furthermore, an answer should be an answer, so please ask for clarifications in a comment instead.

Comment: I did ask for more information into the comments but the comments section was so short one could not ask for everything that was missing. I've been in IT almost 40 years now. Providing links to actual bug reports is never bad practice.